# Converting different code from MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'mm currently going through the process of changing my code and have hit a bit of a wall so thought id ask and see if anyone can help me with the new code...

firstly i have quite a few **mysql_result()** dotted around my code and would like to know how to write the code for the new process.. here is an example of one of my functions that has code that needs changing, I've done some its the **mysql_result()** part that I need to know how to rewrite..

```
function user_exists($db,$username) {
    $username = sanitize($db,$username);
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

    return(mysql_result($sql, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Also while I'm here I may as well ask.. I also have this function to, well *sanitize* code but i keep reading that **mysql_real_escape_string** is not so safe. I've read that i should be using **prepared statements**, I'm just not to sure how to implement it into my code..here is the sanitize function that is basically just **mysql_real_escape_string()**..

```
function sanitize($db, $data) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data);   
}
```

so how would i make this correct? cause from what im reading its just putting **prepare** before a query like..

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

so my question is, can anyone help me change these codes to correct up-to date versions?

Comment: Dude. I don't know where you all get this awful function to convert, but you are nearly 100th who come here asking to rewrite it.

Comment: According to site search, you are actually 76th. the problem with this function is that it is terrible awful as is, and it would be no better even rewritten.

Comment: Using, `$db` inside function without globally calling it in, will cause an error! Also, if you are using mysql class, then you don't have to worry about mysql safety.

Comment: @YourCommonSense which function are you on about? plus im not asking you to rewrite it. I ask for help to rewrite it, so i actually learn what im doing to the code so its one less reason for me to come back and ask for more help..well why dont u tell me and help me understand why its such a terrible function? i learnt from doing tutorials and if my code is awful, instead just pointing it out why dont u offer help, point me in the right direction to improve my code. just saying its bad aint going to help make it any better

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas i havent called $db globally yet but other functions have seemed to work fine so far. is it worth changing it? or as its working, should i just see and wait till it causes me a problem

Comment: This is not your code actually. This code is so much repeated and constantly asked for rewriting, that I hardly believe you are one who wrote it initially.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas both your statements are wrong.

Comment: Ok, the problem here is that the community is all about the problems. So **If its working, don't fix it!**. Asking code optimizations is pointless, because 99% out of those questions my reply would be 1600.00 EUR, and I will recode everything! Use micro float timing to test your codes, which is the fastest, is the most optimized.

Comment: @Your Common Sense Actually your are right. Didn't see the $db coming in. Which makes the function actually even worse. Still, importing it as global would make a neater code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok, i apologising for saying 'my code' as i didnt write it, i followed a tutorial, clearly seems like its the same as all them others. And as it worked in other little projects ive just used it again. and since it worked i had no reason to go out and improve it as i didnt know it needed improving, i do now so clearly i know what i have to do, but if i may ask, what about it makes it so terrible?

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas so i get why making code neater is better, but is that the only reason why i should import as global?

Comment: The only problem with this code is that it was initially written by someone who had not a lightest idea what are they doing. The rest is just consequences. So, better stick to one from the answer.

Comment: I am also curious, why everyone is asking to rewrite this very function only. As though they have no other functions but only this sole one.

Comment: Also, `" just putting prepare before a query"` - where did you read this?

Comment: well for me, i asked as i would hope to take what i learnt and apply it to other functions as i go along, well try to anyway... and im trying to find the page, what i can remember was that, they said you dont use mysql_result no more, you need to use prepared statements. and it was either a 2 step thing, i just cant seem to remember fully, but the 1st step was writing writing the code like i did above, with prepare in it. i guess i just hoped someone will explain what im missing so i can fix it.. id much rather be pointed to an answer instead of just being given the answer

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the PDO Class and bind values (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

So something like the following should work:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute([$username]);
return $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: That looks like a more efficient version of my code @Your Common Sense (and I've realised I could probably do with tweaking some of my code) but I think to someone new to PDO it's really not clear what's happening.

Comment: Bloated code doesn't make it clear either. It just adds some gospel which poor users learn by heart an then repeat with much zeal but less understanding.